# Can one module include two outputs in R shiny?

Tags: r, module, shiny, output, render

Can one module include two outputs in R shiny?

From the App.R file, I am calling a module that includes a data table and a chart.
However, it is not showing on the shiny web without any error.

I am wondering if one module cannot handle two outputs. The reason I am having two outputs in one module and that The chart is based on the data set, being used to produce the data table. if I create additional module for the chart, I will have to have one another query to get the data frame from database again.

What should I do? should I just have another module with another query?

Comment: It is certanly possible. I currently develop modules that have tons of outputs. Can you be more specific about your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: **yes they can!**

Here is an example of a module that contains *two outputs*: a button and a text.

```
library(shiny)

myModuleServer <- function(input, output, session){
  ns <- session$ns
  output$out1 <- renderText({
      paste("Button has been pressed", input$btn, "times")
    })
  output$out2 <- renderUI({
    actionButton(ns("btn"), "btn_label")
  }) 
}

myModuleUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidPage(
    textOutput(ns('out1')),
    uiOutput(ns('out2'))
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Module example"),
  myModuleUI('module_id')
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  callModule(myModuleServer, 'module_id')
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My guess is you ran into complications with *namespaces*. That happened to me a lot when I started using modules at all (obviously) but also when I started using *external libraries* like `shinyBS`, `shinyjs` etc.. For some functions it was *not necessary to use the `ns` function*, for some it was.

One concrete example is the `shinyjs::disable` function which i had to call with `shinyjs::disable('checkbox')` rather than `shinyjs::disable(ns('checkbox'))`. That is, because `shinyjs` uses `session::ns` in its *internal routines*. See [here](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=NS&type=)